# How can I drop bower and use npm for client-side in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to directly use npm to install `jquery`, `bootstrap`... and remove bower from my project.

What do I have to do for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following two files from your project directory to prevent any dependency on bower packages. Visual Studio should empty out the `wwwroot/lib` folder (make sure this happened, otherwise remove manually).

```
.bowerrc    
bower.json
```

To use NPM modules you'll have to setup something like a `gulp` pipeline. This enables you to pick and choose, and combine it all. The built in bower integration has the (questionable) advantage of being in your `wwwroot`.

This should get you started: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp (use a different location for the modules. You can require the specific pieces you want for the javascript if you don't want to reference the direct file location in the `node_modules`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I serve files installed with npm? How do I make this swap?

Comment: Updated my answer with that. It's not as easy as it was with the Bower integration, but once you have a solid Gulp pipeline it should be smooth sailing.